# String array of image URL in Android GridView

Tags: android, image, url, gridview, webview

I have an array of photos that has been filled with url obtained from webservice.
Now i want to display the photos into a gridview, but i can seem to understand how you do it..

This is the code that i have simplified:

```
public GridView grid1;
public String photos[];


grid1 = (GridView)root.findViewById(R.id.gridphotos);
grid1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,photos ));
grid1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

But it only appears the links text....

Can i use WebView to fill the adapter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own adapter either by extending ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter.
Check out the sample here.. http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/09/android-custom-gridview-example.html

Comment: but you have the images already in your drawable resources!  I only have the url in a array that i got from webservice..

Comment: Just have string variable that holds the image url in the model model class and load the image using any of the image loading libraries.

Comment: I have a string array but then i cant be able to populate the gridview... :( because in the adapter i cant put .setImageResource(url) because its gives error